# Magento Custom Category Attribute File

Tags: php, magento

Is there anyway to upload **.flv** extension on magento custom category attribute?

[image]

I have this certain file upload, and it's frontend input is file,

[image]

Originally it's image, but I changed it to file, but it still doesn't work. It does not upload the video to any of the **media folder** on magento.

Is there any way to upload video on file upload magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your controller again, here is my sample code, I edit from my image uploader, just change `setAllowedExtensions`

```
if (!empty($_FILES['store_upcoming_image_upload']['tmp_name'])) {
     $uploaderUpcoming = new Varien_File_Uploader('store_upcoming_image_upload');
     $uploaderUpcoming->setAllowedExtensions(array('flv'));
     $uploaderUpcoming->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
     $uploaderUpcoming->setFilesDispersion(false);
     $uploaderUpcoming->save(
                            Mage::getBaseDir('media' . DS . 'upcoming_image_upload'
                        );
     $storeModel->setUpcomingImage($uploaderUpcoming->getUploadedFileName());
}
```

hope this help :)